My android app don't have libs and build file
i am trying to add External Library in android.
i searched to various information
but it didn't work.
i think my app environment seem to be different from others.
enter image description here
my app don't have library and build file but others have them
i want to add External Library in library file
should i make library file in person?
i expect that i can use External Library
